# SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific'

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, timestamp-with-timezone

Hi the `SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific'` will return `07/01/2015 2:54:27.699071 AM -07:00` but i require only `07/01/2015 2:54:27 AM i.e (MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM Format)` in us pacific time zone

Answer (score 1):

Use **TO_CHAR** with the required **format model** to get your desired output.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') tm_stamp
  2  FROM dual;

TM_STAMP
----------------------
07/01/2015 03:28:04 AM

SQL>
```

Comment: if i have a column with data type date and if i try to insert into it its throwing error ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: create a table with date as datatype and try to insert into the column created you can see the error throwing out ,the to_char i have already tried @lalit

Comment: If the datatype is DATE, then just use **TO_DATE** with proper `format model` and `nls_date_language` to insert.